# Connecting to deployed postgres instance unsuccessfully `FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user`

Tags: postgresql, centos7, digital-ocean, psql, dbeaver

I have been trying to connect to my deployed postgres instance unsuccessfully and I can't seem to figure it out to properly connect to it. IMPORTANT, I have not made my server public to all connections, I just want to connect to my server through REST and then the server communicates with it through localhost.

Getting passed the ssh is not a problem, the issue is specifically tied to connecting to postgres. Within the cli on my deployment, I can manually connect to the postgres instance, created it's db, added functions/tables and that all works great but I can't use it in the application.

Within a larger json file that has been passed into pm2 as a the config file, it contains the below relevent to postgres.

```
  "postgres": {
    "name": "dbName",
    "user": "dbName",
    "pass": "placeholder_password",
    "method": "md5",
    "port": 5432,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
```

Within the pg_hba.conf, I have the changed all instances of ident and peer to md5 yet it still complains that `FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "dbName"`.

Why is it still trying to connect with ident when I have changed them all to md5? I have tried the default name, postgres in the config file but that has not worked either.

Comment: After you changed pg_hba.conf did you reload the PostgreSQL service? For example: `service postgresql reload`

Answer (score 0):

After you changed pg_hba.conf did you reload the PostgreSQL service? For example: service postgresql reload.

Embarrassingly simple solution completely missed in the tutorial that I was following.